# Replacing labels for cut-break bins using stringr

Tags: r, stringr

I'm trying to generate pretty labels from cut-style bins. The bin names default to structures '(-Inf, -2]' and '(0,1]'. I'd like to replace just the end bins (containing Inf) to read (for example), '< -2'. I'm part of the way there using stringr, but I'm running into two problems:

- Replacing only the Inf values: I can replace the -Inf with <, but I'm not sure how to remove the trailing ']' from only the -Inf. Also, on the positive side replacing I want to replace ", Inf]" with a <, but on the other side of the number - I'm sure this is possible with regexp, but not sure how to make it happen.
- Once I've generated the pretty labels, is there any easy way to sub them in for the old ones? Normally I'd relabel the factors using recode_factor(), but this requires manually entering individual names, which defeats the purpose of creating autogenerated labels.

(As a side note, if I just want to remove all ()[] is there a way to do that without using four different str_replace_all commands? Combining them into a list gives me a length matching error.)

Here is an example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

xbreaks <- c(-Inf, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, Inf)
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1000)) %>%
  mutate(xbins = cut(x, breaks = xbreaks))

labs <- unique(df$xbins)

prettylabs <- str_replace_all(labs, "\\(-Inf,", "< ")
prettylabs <- str_replace_all(prettylabs, "\\, Inf", ">")
prettylabs

# Still need to remove the trailing brackets from the Inf argument only, and switch the location of the ">"
#current output: [1] "(-1,0]"  "(0,1]"   "(1,2]"   "(-2,-1]" "(2>]"    "< -2]"  

#is there any way to combine the first four following commands into a single command? 
# (creating a list generates a length error)
prettylabs2 <- str_replace_all(prettylabs, "\\]", "")
prettylabs2 <- str_replace_all(prettylabs2, "\\[", "")
prettylabs2 <- str_replace_all(prettylabs2, "\\)", "")
prettylabs2 <- str_replace_all(prettylabs2, "\\(", "")
prettylabs2 <- str_replace_all(prettylabs2, ",", " - ")
prettylabs2

#still need to switch placement of the > to before the number
#current output: "-1 - 0"  "0 - 1"   "1 - 2"   "-2 - -1" "2>"      "< -2"
```

The desired output is:
prettylabs: "(-1,0]"  "(0,1]"   "(1,2]"   "(-2,-1]" "> 2"    "< -2"
#need to remove trailing "]" on last two only

prettylabs2: "-1 - 0"  "0 - 1"   "1 - 2"   "-2 - -1" "> 2"    "< -2"
#need to convert 2> to >2

Comment: The first interval is very ambiguous, maybe change the - to something else

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
xbreaks <- c(-Inf, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, Inf)
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1000)) %>%
  mutate(xbins = cut(x, breaks = xbreaks))

labs <- unique(df$xbins)
prettylabs <- str_replace(labs, "\\((.*)\\, Inf\\]", "> \\1")
prettylabs <- str_replace(prettylabs, "\\(-Inf\\,(.*)\\]", "< \\1")
prettylabs <- str_replace(prettylabs, "\\((.*)\\,(.*)\\]", "\\1 - \\2")

labs
#> [1] (-1,0]    (0,1]     (1,2]     (-2,-1]   (2, Inf]  (-Inf,-2]
#> Levels: (-Inf,-2] (-2,-1] (-1,0] (0,1] (1,2] (2, Inf]

prettylabs
#> [1] "-1 - 0"  "0 - 1"   "1 - 2"   "-2 - -1" "> 2"     "< -2"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>